# How can I open a second Visual Studio Code instance from the explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

1. one code instance is open
2. click right mouse click, click, 'open with code'
3. code doesn't act on 'open with code'

[image]

ISSUE: solved with current release of code

Comment: That is normal. If an instance is already running, it uses that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `window.openFilesInNewWindow` to `true` in your `settings.json` file.